# cargo run/build is stuck on last file

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo

When running cargo build or cargo run on a specific rust project (base_names), it gets stuck on the last file. Output:

```
       Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
       Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.47
       Compiling quote v1.0.21
       Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.5
       Compiling proc-macro-hack v0.5.19
       Compiling syn v1.0.102
       Compiling radium v0.6.2
       Compiling tap v1.0.1
       Compiling funty v1.2.0
       Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
       Compiling primes v0.3.0
       Compiling wyz v0.4.0
       Compiling num-traits v0.2.15
       Compiling num-integer v0.1.45
       Compiling num-bigint v0.4.3
       Compiling num-rational v0.4.1
       Compiling num-iter v0.1.43
       Compiling bitvec v0.22.3
       Compiling num-complex v0.4.2
       Compiling num v0.4.0
       Compiling fraction v0.12.0
       Compiling arr_macro_impl v0.1.3
       Compiling arr_macro v0.1.3
       Compiling base_names v0.1.0 (/home/max/Documents/Projects/base_names)
        Building [=========================> ] 43/44: base_names(bin)
```

I've tried:

- cargo clean
- rustup update
- pkill cargo
- pkill rls
- running from vscode and terminal
- trying existing rust projects (they work fine, so it's project-specific)
- creating a new rust project and copying in Cargo.toml + the contents of src

Environment: Linux (Fedora Workstation 36)

Cargo.toml contents:

```
[package]
name = "base_names"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
primes = "0.3.0"
fraction = "0.12.0"
bitvec = "0.22.3"
arr_macro = "0.1.3"
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Check if there's a `clang` process doing anything or not. You might have some murderously complex macro it's trying to grind through, or it's busy linking on a very slow HDD.

Comment: Do you have a `build.rs`?

Comment: The dependencies all compiled, it's your binary that is causing the issue. We can't really help unless you post some of its contents

Comment: I bet it is due to `arr_macro`. If you write `arr![xyz; 99999999]` somewhere in your code, it just manually copies the tokens `xyz` (whatever it may be) exactly 99999999 times into a hard coded array. It does not care what kind of expression `xyz` is. If it is a macro, it will expand to that many macro calls.

Comment: @Locke Thanks, that's probably the issue. Is there a way to get around it though? I need a large array of a struct with a String field (so it can't implement Copy).
Starting with a Vec and turning it to an array after it generated resulted in a stack overflow.
The restriction is that the function to create the Struct needs a reference to previous structs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Locke for figuring it out. I used the arr_macro package to write
`arr![Default::default(); 100_000]`
which expands into 100 000 instances of Default::default(), making compilation take too long.

For cases where:

- you need a list of structs
- the generator needs access to the previous structs
- the trait Copy can't be implemented on your struct

you should use a Vec instead.